# Why is selenium picking up more elements than HTML inspect element shows?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So, I have a simple python script which is supposed to count the number of rows in a table using selenium.

The thing is, when I print using len() it shows 9 but when I inspect the element there are only 4 tr.

How is this happening?

Here is the snippet of the len:

```
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')))
        td = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')
        print(len(td))
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

And here is the sample html structure of the website I am trying to scrape.

Side info: the number of rows below is being defined by an AJAX.

```
<tbody>
 <tr>...</tr>
 <tr>...</tr>
 <tr>...</tr>
 <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

I am also pretty sure that, the above snippet is the one pointing out by xpath as it was the one being highlited by find function of dev console of chrome.

Comment: Are you able to share the site and table you're trying to scrape?

Comment: @Thorium While I can share the website, you will still need to have an approved access to be able to see the part in which the above snippet is at. So sadly, no.

Comment: If you inspect element and then Ctrl+F and search "tr" does anything other than those 4 elements show up?

Comment: @Thorium I was able to figure out. Apparently there is another table and the len also counts the TR of the other table.

Thank you for your time man.

Comment: No worries at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

Apparently, the calendar being displayed also uses Tables and since I started my xpath with // it counts the TR on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for all the table loaded before counting the found `td`.
`visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')` is waiting for the first row in the table only.

Comment: I am confused. If it is waiting for the first row only why I am getting 9 instead of 1?

Comment: Selenium is polling the DOM with some time period, like every 100 milliseconds, not every millisecond. The page is bringing the data from the server in chunks, not byte after byte.

Comment: That is something I should take note of. Thank you @Prophet